# How to run TensorRT in multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, pycuda, tensorrt

I am new to TensorRT and CUDA and I am trying to implement an inference server using TensorRT Python API. I follow the `end_to_end_tensorflow_mnist` and `uff_ssd` example and everything works ok. However, when I try to use the engine to make inference in multiple threads, I encounter some problems. So I was wondering what is the right way to run TensorRT in multiple threads.

Here's what i have tried. First I create inference engine in the main thread. In the worker thread, I allocate memory space, CUDA Stream and execution context using the engine created in the main thread and make inference:

```
import pycuda.autoinit  # Create CUDA context
import pycuda.driver as cuda 

# Main thread
with open(“sample.engine”, “rb”) as f, trt.Runtime(TRT_LOGGER) as runtime:
    engine = runtime.deserialize_cuda_engine(f.read())

...

# Worker thread
with engine.create_execution_context() as context:
    inputs, outputs, bindings, stream = common.allocate_buffers(engine)
    common.do_inference(context, inputs, outputs, bindings, stream)
```

The above code produce the following error:

```
pycuda._driver.LogicError: explicit_context_dependent failed: invalid device context - no currently active context?
```

This sounds like there is no active CUDA context in the worker thread. So, I tried to create CUDA context manually in the worker thread:

```
# Worker thread
from pycuda.tools import make_default_context()
cuda.init()  # Initialize CUDA
ctx = make_default_context()  # Create CUDA context

with engine.create_execution_context() as context:
    inputs, outputs, bindings, stream = common.allocate_buffers(engine)
    common.do_inference(context, inputs, outputs, bindings, stream)

ctx.pop()  # Clean up
```

This time, it gives me another error:

```
[TensorRT] ERROR: cuda/cudaConvolutionLayer.cpp (163) - Cudnn Error in execute: 7
[TensorRT] ERROR: cuda/cudaConvolutionLayer.cpp (163) - Cudnn Error in execute: 7
```

I understand the builder or runtime will be created with the GPU context associated with the creating thread. I guess this error is because the engine is associated with main thread but I use it in the worker thread, so my question is:

1. Is that means I have to rebuild the engine in worker thread, which significantly increase inference overheat?
2. Can I share GPU context between main thread and worker threads so that I don't have to create a new GPU context for each new request? If so, how to do that in pycuda?

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured out a solution yet? The context from `create_execution_context` seems to fail in the worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this](https://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_does_PyCUDA_handle_threading.3F).

You need to modify the `common.py` as below if you want to do inference in multi-thread. Make context before triggering the GPU task:

```
dev = cuda.Device(0) // 0 is your GPU number
ctx = dev.make_context()
```

and clean up after the GPU task:

```
ctx.pop()
del ctx
```

Comment: I've faced same error. I followed your answer and get another error as below: 
[TensorRT] ERROR: ../rtSafe/safeContext.cpp (133) - Cudnn Error in configure: 7 (CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR)

[TensorRT] ERROR: FAILED_EXECUTION: std::exception

Comment: But we need to use TensorRT's `create_execution_context()` function as the context for inference. The above code alongside this function will cause crashes or as @Masha has pointed out result in a CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR.